# Spring Transaction propagation nested Propagation REQUIRES_NEW in Propagation.REQUIRED

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring 3.2 integrate with hibernate 4
Here is my code

```
@Service
public class MyService{

    @AutoWired
    private NestedServcie ns; 

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void outer(){

       while(true){

       dao.findOne();    // This method find data from db using hibernate hql

       ns.inner();     // insert some data and commit and loop again.

       }
    }

}


@Service
public class NestedServcie{

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void inner(){
        //here insert some data into db using hibernate
    }

}
```

Here is the spring config xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

And here is my question
before I run this program, there is no data in db, so dao.findOne() is null in the first loop. But after ns.inner() excute, I insert some data into db and commit (where I think REQUIRES_NEW works). And when the second loop begin, dao.findOne is still null, the outer
can not get the inner insert data. why??

Thanks!!

Comment: What happens when you change in outer to Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW? Or can you check current transaction name before ns.inner() call?

Comment: post the code to your dao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an ongoing transaction which basically has its own version of the data. The newly added data is not visible to that transaction. Next to that you have hibernate in the mix, which uses caching and depending on what is executed, the query is only executed once and on subsequent calls it simply returns the cached values (within the same transaction/session for instance).

Links

- [Can/Should spring reuse hibernate session for sub transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466253/can-should-spring-reuse-hibernate-session-for-sub-transaction-requires-new)
- [Transaction Isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems))
- [Visibility of objects in different hibernate sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842357/visibility-of-objects-in-different-hibernate-sessions)

Comment: Thanks, the code in dao is very simple, just use SessionFactory .getCurrentSession.createQuery to execute a select query which find out the maximum primary key record. I user @Generatedvalue to gen primary key id when insert a new record. I also try to flush the session after ns.inner execute, but it doesn't work

Comment: A flush is only issuing pending statements to the database. You have 2 independent transactions, in general the outer transaction will not see the data from the inner transaction (depending on database that is). Just for test annotate your `dao.findOne()` in such a way that it starts a new transaction.

Comment: And if I change the inner propagation to REQUIRED. It works fine, at second loop, dao.findOne is not null. I try to use proxy to get what sql is excuted and find that when using Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, when inner is excuted, spring will send a commit to db, but why the outer can not get the "real time" data??

Comment: Finally to see what is happening enable 'DEBUG' logging for spring en watch the session getting created/transaction committed etc.

Comment: Because it are 2 seperate isolated transactions and sessions, as mentioned a started transaction looks at a certain "snapshot" of the data (how etc. depends on the database). If you commit/flush in the same session the data is available for the current transaction, whereas it isn't if a new transaction is used.

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation! I think I have to try another solution.

Comment: I've added some links to (i think) useful resources.